# Why I'm seeing this when I do npm install

Tags: npm, puppeteer

After running npm I'm seeing this error.  How do I resolve it?

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.20.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-17T15_35_46_212Z-debug.log
```

I ran:

```
npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command:

```
npm config set puppeteer_skip_chromium_download true -g
```

And then try to install again

Answer (score 3):

```
PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true npm install puppeteer
```

helped me